# is possible to have accent sensitive and case insensitive utf8 collation in mysql?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

How can I perform accent-sensitive but case-insensitive utf8 search in mysql? Utf8_bin is case sensitive, and utf8_general_ci is accent insensitive.

Comment: Not today...  But, if you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be one  because [case sensitivity is  tough to do in Unicode](https://serverfault.com/questions/137415/change-collation-of-a-mysql-table-to-utf8-general-cs).

There is a `utf8_general_cs` collation but it seems to be experimental, and according to [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50909), doesn't do what it's expected to when using LIKE.

If your data consists of western umlauts only (ie. umlauts that are included in ISO-8859-1), you might be able to collate your search operation to `latin1_german2_ci` or create a separate search column with it (that specific collation is accent sensitive according to [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html); `latin1_general_ci` might be as well, I don't know and can't test right now).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to differ "café" from "cafe"
You may use :

```
Select word from table_words WHERE Hex(word) LIKE Hex("café");
```

This way it will return 'café'.

Otherwise if you use :

```
Select word from table_words WHERE Hex(word) LIKE Hex("cafe");
```

it will return café.
I'm using the latin1_german2_ci Collation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "`hex`" to make the search accent-sensitive. Then simply add lcase to make it case insensitive again. So that would give:

```
SELECT name FROM people WHERE HEX(LCASE(name)) = HEX(LCASE("René"))
```

You do throw all your indexes out of the window like that. If you want to avoid having to do a full table scan and you have an index on "name", also search for the same thing without the hex and lcase:

```
SELECT name FROM people WHERE name = "René" and HEX(LCASE(name)) = HEX(LCASE("René"))
```

This way the index on "`name`" will be used to find for example only the rows "`René`" and "Rene" and then the comparison with the "`hex`" needs to be done only on those two rows instead of on the complete table.

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .